# Dynamic sub-string in batch file

Tags: batch-file, substring, echo

Code Excerpt of my batch file:

```
set stringOne=ABCDEF    
echo %stringOne:~2,3%
```

This output is `CDE`

How can I dynamically `echo` the output for my start index and desired output length?

```
set stringOne=ABCDEF  
set start=2  
set len=3
```

Comment: This type of management is described at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990), although the topic is different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two layers of variable expansion. That can be done by [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) or by `call`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=ABCDEFGH"
set "start=2"
set "len=3"

echo A with delayed expansion: !string:~%start%,%len%!
call echo A with using 'call': %%string:~%start%,%len%%%

FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /b "%~f0"') DO ( 
  set /A "newStart=!Start!+2" 
  call echo B with 'call' and delayed : %%string:~!newStart!,!len!%%
  call call echo B with double-'call': %%%%string:~%%newStart%%,%len%%%%% 
)

FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /b "%~f0"') DO call :output
goto :eof
:output
  set /A "newStart=Start+2" 
  echo C with subroutine and delayed expansion: !string:~%newStart%,%len%! 
  call echo C with subroutine andusing 'call': %%string:~%newStart%,%len%%% 
goto :eof
```

**EDITED** to match your comment. You need a third layer of expansion. I expanded the code with some different methods.
(btw: please don't post code in comments, it's nearly impossible to read. And if your question changes, better ask a follow-up question next time)

Comment: with delayed expansion: CDE
with using 'call': CDE

But,
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=ABCDEFG"
set "start=2"
set "len=3"
FOR /F %%G IN ('dir /b *.txt') DO (
 set "fileName=%%G"
 set /A "newStart=!Start!+2"
 echo !newStart!
 echo with delayed expansion: !string:~%newStart%,%len%!
 call echo with using 'call': %%string:~%newStart%,%len%%%
)
O/P
4
with delayed expansion: ABC  (instead of EFG)
with using 'call': ABC  (instead of EFG)

How I will be able to get the output EFG ?